# Best practice advise for deleting tables in PHP/MySQL framework?

Tags: mysql, web-frameworks

What are some best practices tips for tinkering, deleting tables, making reversible changes in MySQL (not production) testing server? In my case I'm learning a PHP/MySQL framework.

The only general tool I have in my toolbox is to rename files before I delete them. If there is a problem I can always return a file to its original name. I would imagine it should be OK to apply the same practice to a database, since clients can lose their connection to a host. Yet, how does a *web application framework* proceed when *referential integrity* is broken only in one place?

Comment: Which framework, a real one or your own? Database wrapper, is it an ORM, and id so which one, or just calls/functions etc.? No you cannot really treat database tables like files and how does the framework handle broken RI, well how is the code designed to work when RI fails? That is what it will do. And by the way whoever marked this up by 1 needs their head checking and or maybe should add a comment as to why they think it is a good question.

Comment: @PurplePilot: You're an angry Pilot, and your sentences are not... Maybe slow down your response time, then you won't appear to be both helpful and scornful at the same time? In answer to your request for clarification, my interest is with "real" frameworks for Content Management. Not "fake" frameworks, or whatever the other frameworks id or isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to transactions. InnoDB engine in MySQL supports transactions as well as Foreign Key constraints.

In transactional design, you can execute a bunch of queries that need to be executed as a single entity in order to be meaningful and to maintain data integrity. A transaction is started and if something goes wrong it does a Rollback, thus reverting every change done so far, or committing the entire set of modifications in the database.

Foreign keys are constraints for referential data. Thus in a master-detail relationship you cannot e.g. refer to a master record that does not exist. If there is a table *comments* with a user_id referring to the *users.id* field , you are not allowed to enter a comment for a non-existent user.

Read more here if you will 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html
and for foreign keys
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: I gathered from the transaction link, "In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction.". This implies this model refers to database plan or design. My question is not about users, or planning data's referential integrity. I'm only referring to administrating the data. And in this case the data of a framework, but not through the application's API.